# Perform action on first file in each subdirectory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to perform a command on the alphabetically first file in a set of subdirectories using

```
for /R "parentfolder" %%a in (*.doc) do "%winword%" /mRTF "%%a"
```

in a batch file. The actual command and macro work fine, but it performs the action on each file in the directories instead of just the ones I want.

Is there a way to set the -on flags in this context?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

---

Thank you that got me a good bit further.

Currently I'm struggling with opening word and running the Macro through powershell. My code looks like this now:

```
$word = new-object -comobject word.application
$path = 'C:\Users\---\Desktop\Download\'
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse | SELECT Attributes, Name |  where-Object{ $_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'} | ForEach-Object{$_.name}
 foreach ($folder in $folders){
   Get-ChildItem -Path $path$folder |
   Select-Object -First 1 |
   ForEach-Object { notepad $_.FullName }
 }
```

I try to change notepad to word and call the macro but so far no luck

Comment: Is the word executable not called **win**word.exe?

Comment: unfortunately it's not that easy :-(

Comment: It wasn't a solution, just an observation that typing `word` to invoke an executable named `winword` is never going to work unless you had pre-created a method of 'linking' the names.

Comment: You are right with that. For the batch scrript I defined it, for the Powershell i used the first line from the amended script $word=... and replaced the notepad with word. But it still doesn't work

Comment: BTW, you haven't made it clear if you are trying to invoke your command on the alphabetically first file from all of the sub folders or the alphabetically first file from each sub folder. Also it would be helpful if the folder structure was known, or if you explained whether by sub folder you are excluding sub sub folders or sub sub sub folders etc.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. There is one parent folder with x sub directories which contain text files. The operation should be performed on the first file in each sub-directorie. By now I solved the problem with bash, however I'd still be curious how the filter could be set in the for /R version of the batch script.

Comment: I would suggest you forget about using **`/R`**, that would recurse every level of the tree. You don't need to do that because your intent is to work only 1 level into the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in PowerShell. I used notepad.exe, but you can use whatever you want.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    ForEach-Object { notepad "$_.FullName" }
```

If you -must- do this from a cmd shell .bat script, you could:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' ^| ^
    Select-Object -First 1 ^| ^
    ForEach-Object { notepad \"$($_.FullName)\" }
```

HT to mklement0 for the escape.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your example code and subsequent comments, the below example may run your Word macro on each of the files you require:

```bat
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /D %%A In ("parentfolder\*") Do (Set "_="
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir/B/A-D-S-L/O-N "%%A\*.doc" 2^>Nul'
    ) Do Set "_=%%B"
    If Defined _ "%winword%" /mRTF "%%A\!_!")
```